Deploying Flask app and React app to a VPS
ive built a webapp using react and python, my app is a inventory system for my schools science department but im having issues deploying it to my VPS, the backend is made in python using flask while the frontend is JS using react. ive tried for the past 3 days to deploy it but still no luck, the project can be found here: https://github.com/mharrington07/Chem-Inv if you have any advice or even are willing to call i'd appreciate it so much(just reach out).
first i will tell you that on my own windows 10 machine running the backend using venv works great, then running a production version of the front end by using
npm run build
npm serve -s build
this start the backend and frontend on my local network(as expected) so thus any device on my network can view it and add or remove items from the backends database.
second, I got a VPS from hetzner running ubuntu 20.04, I used git to install the project, i first setup the backend going into my virtual env and installing all required pip packages, then use gunicorn and systemd to run the backend, creating a systemd service file
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/yourapp.service
and writing the following:https://hastebin.skyra.pw/uyadatopit.ini
then starting and enabling the service:
sudo systemctl start yourapp.service
sudo systemctl enable yourapp.service
finishing the backend(idk if i did anything right, ive never done anything like this before sorry)
now the frontend, after install the npm packages and building the app
npm install
npm run build
I decided to use nginx(that seems like what everyone uses) starting with
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
https://hastebin.skyra.pw/vijubirate.nginx
then running
sudo systemctl restart nginx
after this i went to my VPS ip where the frontend react worked great, the website appeard as it should but when i went to add an item using the input boxes and submit button nothing changed, checking the logs for the backends gunicorn service showed https://hastebin.skyra.pw/idatinilug.pgsql, after this i spent several nights trying other option but i feel like this post is getting really long but to no avail i even reset my vps to make sure it wasnt something i accedently did as im not familiar with linux that much. example video here: https://streamable.com/4s04e7
I've tried configuring nginx twenty different ways along with configuring the gunicorn and other common issues and i just cant figure it out
